# I receive an "FirebaseSimpleLogin: An unknown error occurred" in Firebase when I try to log in with Twitter

Tags: javascript, web, twitter-oauth, firebase

Yesterday, I discovered Firebase and started to use it. I deployed an edited version (I just changed the CSS) of the chat app provided by Firebase, Everything went OK until I added Twitter Logging option. I couldn't authenticate my app with Twitter even though I followed [these instructions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-twitter.html) and I activated "Sign in with Twitter" from Twitter Application Management Panel.

This is the code I'm using in my chat app to log in (anything else is related to Twitter logging in my code):

```
// instatiate the FirebaseSimpleLogin and monitor the user's auth state
var chatRef = new Firebase('https://ranchat.firebaseIO.com');
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(chatRef, function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
// an error occurred while attempting login
alert(error);
  } else if (user) {
// user authenticated with Firebase
  alert('Welcome' + user.username);
  } else {
// user is logged out
  }
});

// attempt to log the user in with your preferred authentication provider
$('#twlog').click(function(){
  auth.login('twitter', {
  RememberMe: true
  });
});
```

These are the Firebase Rules I'm using

```
 {
 "rules": {
 ".read": true,
 "$comment": {
   ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.child('twitter_id').val() == auth.id"
   }
  }
 }
```

And this is what happens after press Twitter Log button in [my app](https://ranchat.firebaseapp.com)

> Error: FirebaseSimpleLogin: An unknown error occurred

Honesly, I don't know why it happening. Would you give a hand?

Comment: I'd recommend reaching out to Firebase support at support@firebase.com

Comment: Also, I would recommend verifying that you correctly copied your Twitter Client Id and Client Secret into Firebase Forge.

Comment: Hi @RobDiMarco. I did everything one more time and it worked! Apparently, the problem was the API key and API secret; I didn´t copy it properly, I guess. 

Thanks a lot for make me see the issue from other angle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to @RobDiMarco.

The error was occuring due to an incorrect copy of Twitter *API ID* and *API Secret* into my Firebase Forge. I just needed to copy [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McIcN.jpg) and then paste it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcylK.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

The terminology is very confusing in Firebase Simple Login documentation. Firebase requires three things:

- **Twitter App ID** (used in the client call), which is the "API key" from API keys tab in your Twitter application settings page
- **Twitter Consumer Key** (entered into Firebase Forge), which is also the "API key"
- **Twitter Consumer Secret** (entered into Firebase Forge), which is the "API secret" from the same tab